# Copy constructor create garbage objects

Tags: java, oop, constructor, garbage

My teacher gave me 2 classes, one is passport and the other is date.
 date contain 3 attributes (string day,string month, string year), getters, setters and 2 constructors, one of them is a copy constructor:

```
 public date(date dt)
 this.day=dt.getd();
 this.month=dt.getm();
 this.yaer=dt.gety();
```

passport class contain 2 attributes (string name, date exp(from date class))and there is this construcor:

```
public passport(string name, date exp)   
this.name=name;  
this.exp= new date(exp);
```

now in the main class, every time i create new date and new passport, every date is duplicate and i get 1 garbage object for every passport.
how can i get over this garbage object?

Comment: If your teacher really gave you `date` and `passport` classes, you might want to suggest that he/she respect standard Java naming conventions, in which class names are initially-capped and CamelCase. So the classes would be `Date` and `Passport`. (Or he/she might want to use a different name for `Date` to avoid confusion with the two `Date` classes already in the JDK.) Using standard naming conventions makes it easier for other people to read your code. No Java teacher should be using all-lower-case class names, and it makes one ask whether that teacher really knows what they're doing in Java.

Comment: What exactly so you mean by "1 garbage object"?

Comment: Probably also worth mentioning that standard naming would use whole works in method names, e.g., `getDay`, not `getd`.

Answer (score 0):

> how can i get over this garbage object?

If `date` instances are mutable, you don't; you do what you're doing.

if `date` instances are *immutable* (their state cannot be changed once they've been created), then you just use the instance you're given rather than creating a new one:

```
public passport(string name, date exp)   
    this.name = name;  
    this.exp = exp;
}
```

You wouldn't want to do that if `exp` could be modified, because it would create cross-talk between your `passport` instance and whatever passed the `exp` to it.

Comment: date can be mutable and thats why she gave us the copy constructor. i though about using a for loop in the main that overwrite the first date object every time.

Comment: @3xhaust: No idea what you're talking about with a `for` loop in the `main` (as you haven't shown us `main`), but if `date` is mutable, you create a new date the way you are. It's called a defensive copy, and it correct practice here.

Comment: There's no point in a copy constructor if a class is immutable.

Comment: @Michael: Not a pure copy constructor, no, quite so. I was just being thorough. (And given the apparent quality of the code provided by the teacher, we can't be sure of anything. :-) ) A class with immutable instances would typically instead expose methods allowing you to "modify" (through copying) one or more properties getting back a new instance with the modified properties, e.g., `date withDays(int days)` would return a `date` with the same month and year but the given days value.

Answer (score 0):

> how can i get over this garbage object?

Let the garbage collector does its job : as the `Date` variable passed as parameter to the `Passport` constructor will be out of scope of the execution context, the underlying `Date` object will be eligible to be collected.

The way the most straight to do it is to not assign the `Date` object to a variable. 
Just inline its instantiation in the `Passport` constructor invocation :

```
Passport passport = new Passport(name, new Date(day, month, year));
```

Answer (score 0):

optional solution:

in the main class:

```
passport[] arr = new passport[100];   // we have 100 passports
date d1= new date ()                  //null date
for (int i=0,i<100,i++)               // we have 100 passports
{ d1.setd();                          //our setter asks for an input
  d1.setm();
  d1.sety();
  arr [i]=new passport (string name, d1); }
```